# Can SQL server profiler monitor a specfic user that connects with application user?

Tags: sql-server

I run profiler in SQL that connects to application, 
all the users of the application are connecting to 
the SQL with application user.

Can I monitor a specific user? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If the application uses a fat client (something that runs locally on the user's machine), you can filter via HostName.  You may have to select "Show All Columns" to see this option.

If it's a web application that connects from a web server, I don't know of any way to monitor a specific user.